# Iterative permutations, but favoring swaps of early elements

Tags: algorithms, permutations, enumeration

I'm familiar with the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm), which allows for the iterative yielding of permutations of a sequence by performing a single swap per iteration.  It has the behavior, however, that it tends to swap elements further along the sequence early in the iteration.  For 4 elements, my understanding is that the first 6 permutations will be:

$1,2,3,4$

$1,2,4,3$

$1,4,2,3$

$4,1,2,3$

$4,1,3,2$

$4,3,1,2$

What I'd like to know is whether there is similar iterative algorithm, using relatively simple changes (though obviously can't be single swaps) that yields a sequence:

$1,2,3,4$

$2,1,3,4$

$1,3,2,4$

$2,3,1,4$

$3,1,2,4$

$3,2,1,4$

---

Per request, here is my attempt at a better definition of the desired result:

1. Start with the initial sequence of $n$ elements and yield it.
2. For each $i \in \{2..n\}$, then $k \in \{1..i\}$
3. Take the element $x_i$ and place it at position $i-k$.  We will now consider the first $i$ elements and keep the remaining $n-i$ elements the same.
4. Yield all permutations of the remaining $i-1$ elements (using these rules) surrounding the position $i-k$.

Basically the goal is to permute each initial sequence fully before continuing to permute with later elements.